# Error message when trying to create a new layer using the Spatial Query tool

Tags: qgis, spatial-query

Simply trying to create a new layer where points (which represent tick occurrence) are contained within a UK boundary shapefile as opposed to working with points for the whole of Europe. When I try and do this I get the following error message:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please remember to always include the error message as ASCII text in the body of the question (which makes it both legible and searchable). Please [Edit] the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to the problem:

The point data set was derived from a csv file which was in an unsupported format. I converted the point layer to a shapefile with the right coordinate system and it worked.